# Changing adapter back to managed mode

Tags: wireless

I changed my adapter to monitor mode using:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
```

Now, I cannot change it back (in the GUI, when I click on connections, it says that "wireless is disabled by wireless switch"). I have not switched off anything using the hardware buttons.

I tried:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed 
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I also tried:

```
pccardctl eject
pccardctl insert
```

It appears that it has switched back to managed mode, but is still offline:

`ifconfig` output:

```
 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:21:6f:84:69  
           inet addr:10.100.1.41  Bcast:10.100.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::224:21ff:fe6f:8469/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:27668 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:3504 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:1 txqueuelen:1000 
           RX bytes:4493143 (4.4 MB)  TX bytes:659945 (659.9 KB)
 
 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
           RX packets:553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
           RX bytes:84110 (84.1 KB)  TX bytes:84110 (84.1 KB)
```

`iwconfig` output:

```
 eth0      no wireless extensions.
 
 lo        no wireless extensions.
 
 wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
           Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
           Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:off
```

Answer (score 5):

You should execute:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

And it should come back to life.

Just to give you a little explanation: the output of the command `ifconfig` only shows the interfaces that are up. For example, you'll notice that your `eth0` interface is up:

```
eth0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:21:6f:84:69  
           inet addr:10.100.1.41  Bcast:10.100.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::224:21ff:fe6f:8469/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Your `ifconfig` output does not have `wlan0` listed, meaning that it has been turned off. If you do `ifconfig -a`, you should see all interfaces (up or down), and you'll notice that `wlan0` won't have **`UP`** displayed. And all of this makes complete sense because you switched off your WiFi card when you did `ifconfig wlan0 down`. So `ifconfig wlan0 up` should bring it back online. If it doesn't work straight away, do a `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: You can also use `sudo ip link set dev wlan0 up` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Alpha-Lead's script on GitHub.
It provides a nice and easy menu to change modes.
https://github.com/Alpha-Lead/ChangeWirelessMode

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I need to turn the radio on at the last step.

```
ip link dev up     
nmcli radio all on
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the answers provided on the Internet but none of them were working.

Finally, I got my answer and here it is:

```
sudo su
airmon-ng stop wlan0 && ifconfig wlan0 down && iwconfig wlan0 mode managed && ifconfig wlan0 up && service NetworkManager restart
```

Here, `wlan0` is the network interface name. If yours is different, then change it accordingly.

You must remember to run these commands as super user.

Answer (score 0):

## With [`ip`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html) and [`iw`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iw)

This gets you back to managed mode and establishes a Wi-Fi connection with your wireless router:

```
ip link set wlp3s0 down
iw wlp3s0 set type managed
ip link set wlp3s0 up
systemctl restart NetworkManager
nmcli con up your_networks_SSID
```

In this example, `wlp3s0` is the name of your Wi-Fi interface.

The key here is to set the interface state to down to avoid `iw`'s error message:

> command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)